# Endomorphisms of the multiplicative group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $U$ be an open subscheme of the spectrum $X=\mathrm{Spec}(O_K)$ of the ring of integers of a number field. Let $\mathbb{G}_m$ be the étale sheaf represented by the multiplicative group. Do we know how to compute
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_U(\mathbb{G}_m,\mathbb{G}_m)
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{Ext}^1_U(\mathbb{G}_m,\mathbb{G}_m) 
$$
?
I'm a bit at a loss here. It would be nice if the first ext group was finite or at least torsion.

Comment: Does $\mathrm{Hom}_U(\mathbb{G}_m,\mathbb{G}_m)$ mean the morphisms $R[x,x^{-1}]\to S[x,x^{-1}]$ with $Frac(R)=Frac(S)=K$ and $U \subset Spec(R) ,U \subset Spec(S) $ ? Since every endomorphism of $K[x,x^{-1}]$ is of the form $x\mapsto x^n$ defined over $\Bbb{Z}$ it would be $\{x\mapsto x^n\} \cong \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @reuns That is correct. It's true over any connected base. You can see the exercise of Conrad linked in my answer to see how to prove this over any base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Now that I have more time I'll give a more precise answer.

> **Claim:** Let $S$ be a normal integral scheme, then $\mathrm{Ext}^1_{S_\mathrm{et}}(\mathbb{G}_m,\mathbb{G}_m)=0$.

*Proof:* Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an etale sheaf given as an extension

$$0\to \mathbb{G}_m\to\mathcal{F}\to\mathbb{G}_m\to 0$$

Note then that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsor over $\mathbb{G}_m$ and so by etale descent for affine morphisms of schemes we know that $\mathcal{F}$ is representable by some affine group scheme $T$. We claim that $T$ is a torus (in the sense of Definition 3.1.1 of [Con1]). But, by Theorem B.4.1 of [Con1] it suffices to show that $T_{\overline{s}}$ is a torus for every geometric point $\overline{s}$ of $S$. But, this reduces us to the case when $S$ is the spectrum of an algebraically closed field $k$. Note then that $T$ is a smooth affine group scheme and so by Corollary 12.21 of [Mil] it suffices to show that $T(k)$ consists only of semisimple elements. But this is immediately from the fact that $T$ is an extension of $\mathbb{G}_m$ by itself and the fact that Jordan decomposition is functorial.

So, now that we know that $T$ is a torus it suffices by Corollary B.3.6 of [Con1] to show that the continuous representation $\pi_1^\mathrm{et}(S,\overline{s})\to \mathrm{GL}(X^\ast(T))$ is trivial. But, note that by the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is an extension of $\mathbb{G}_m$ we know that $\pi_1^\mathrm{et}(S,\overline{s})$ takes values in $\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & \ast\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\right\}\cong\mathbb{Z}$. In other words, $T$ corresponds to a continuous homomomorphism $\pi_1^\mathrm{et}(S,\overline{s})\to \mathbb{Z}$. But, there is no non-trivial such homomorphism since $\pi_1^\mathrm{et}(S,\overline{s})$ is profinite. $\blacksquare$

TL;DR: There are no non-trivial continuous homomorphisms $\pi_1^\mathrm{et}(S,\overline{s})\to \mathbb{Z}$.

Note that this TL;DR also indicates what could go wrong over a non-normal base. Namely, while there are no non-continuous homomorphisms $\pi_1^\mathrm{et}(S,\overline{s})\to \mathbb{Z}$ for an arbitrary irreducible scheme $S$, there *are* non-trivial homomorphisms $\pi_1^{\mathrm{proet}}(S,\overline{s})\to \mathbb{Z}$ or $\pi_1^{\mathrm{SGA}3}(S,\overline{s})\to \mathbb{Z}$. The point is that B.3.6 of [Con1] can be stated for arbitrarly irreducible $S$ if one replaces $\pi_1^{\mathrm{et}}(S,\overline{z})$ with $\pi_1^{\mathrm{proet}}(S,\overline{s})$ or $\pi_1^{\mathrm{SGA}3}(S,\overline{s})$. So, for example the claim is false since, for example, if $S$ is the projective nodal curve then $\pi^{\mathrm{proet}}(S,\overline{s})\cong \pi_1^{\mathrm{SGA}3}(S,\overline{s})\cong \mathbb{Z}$ as topological groups.

Your first question is more elementary--the answer is $\mathbb{Z}$. See Exercise 1 [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf) for a guided solution.

[Con1] *Reductive group schemes*, Brian Conrad, -- found [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf).

[Con2] http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/252Page/homework/hmwk1.pdf

[Mil] *Algebraic groups: the theory of finite type group schemes over a field*, Milne, published by Cambridge press.